# Check if letters in list add up to a variable

Tags: python

Lets say I have a list `letters = ["a", "c", "t"]`, how would I check if those letters could make the word "cat"?

Comment: `guessed_letters.append(letter)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [append vs. extend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/append-vs-extend)

Comment: @PeterWood You'd have to sort both sides before comparing.

Comment: How would I convert the list to be in the order that the word is? So how would I make this list ['c', 'a', 't']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why your question is drawing so much bad attention. `permutations` are what you need:

```
from itertools import permutations

def is_perm(letters,word):
    for p in permutations(letters):
        if ''.join(p) == word: return True
    return False
letters = ["a", "c", "t"]
word = 'cat'
print is_perm(letters,word)
```

Letters may of course be any list of strings, not just letters.

Comment: It used to be a different question, but I changed that. However since then it's still been going down. Not sure why, too. Thanks for the help tho. :)

Comment: I did not personally downvote, but I believe others may have done so because you did not show that you attempted anything before asking the question.

Comment: + Elliot Roberts Makes sense I guess.

Comment: People should really comment when they downvote, it's polite and helpful. Otherwise you're missing the point of stackexchange, helping (IMO).

Comment: @kabanus people also tend to downvote answers to lazy questions, to discourage users from answering them. I guess this is what happened here.

Comment: @HughChalmers if this answers your question you should mark it accepted with the check mark to the left `<------`

Answer (score 0):

This would do the job. It checks to see if all of the letters are in the word, and all of the word letters are in the list.

```
letters = ['c', 'a', 't']
word = "cat"

def check_word(lst, word):
    for letter in lst:
        if letter not in word:
            return False # "this series does not work"

    for letter in list(word):
        if letter not in lst:
            return False # "this series does not work"


    return True # "this works"

check_word(letters, word) # returns True
```